# Move to next Edittext automatically after entering number

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a layout where i have 4 circular `edittext` to enter PIN.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/four_pin_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>
  <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/four_pin_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>

  <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/four_pin_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/four_pin_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want like after entering number for first `edittext`, it should automatically move to next `edittext`.
Now after tapping on next `edittext` or after tapping on next button from soft keyboard only i am able to enter number.
Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps it will give you your desired result :-

Update your XML with ids in `EditTexts` like this :-

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id ="@+id/firstET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/four_pin_background"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:cursorVisible="false"/>
      <EditText
               android:id ="@+id/secondET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/four_pin_background"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then inside your JAVA Code ,

Take Reference of these `EditTexts` , and add this code inside your `onCreate()` method of your Activity like :-

```
EditText firstET , secondET;

firstET = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.firstET); 
secondET = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id. secondET);


firstET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         // add a condition to check length here - you can give here length according to your requirement to go to next EditTexts.
         if(firstET.getText().toString().trim().length() >2){
         firstET.clearFocus();
         firstET.requestFocus();
       }
      } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Thunder, It is working for me. Can you please tell me one thing.That on keyboard X(back) button clicked it should remove number from edittext one by one .How to do this.

Comment: your welcome @ananya , if you click on 'x' it removes one character by one character only right

Answer (score 2):

Attach a `TextWatcher`

Check for needed length of `editText` input and focus next.

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == PIN_LENGTH) {
                focusNext();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**`addTextChangedListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

> Adds a TextWatcher to the list of those whose methods are called whenever this EditText's text changes.

**Sample Code**

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                                 // specify length of your editext here to move on next edittext
            if(editText.getText().toString().trim().length()>=1){
                NexteditText.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```